# new Date() function and moment() do not detect inputs with characters at the beginning and ending with numbers such as 'abc 12' as an invalid date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am expecting a functionality to check if a given string is Date or not; Given I may have a string that contains numbers and not only string in it.

Input is

```
'abc 12'
```

As we know 'abc 12' is not a valid date string yet, new Date() and moment consider it as a valid date string and give an output.

```
new Date('abc 12')
```

Expected Output -

```
Invalid Date
```

Actual Output -

```
Sat Dec 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I also tried using moment

```js
var moment = require("moment");
var currentDate = moment('abc 123').toString()
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = currentDate;
```

Expected Output -

```
Invalid date
```

Actual Output -

```
Fri Jan 01 0123 00:00:00 GMT+0600
```

Comment: Do you know the format of date you receve and insert in `moment("...")`?

Comment: The format may change there is no fixed format.

Comment: I am the author's acquintance. The data comes from Api. Its a generic field, it can come with plain string or an iso date string. We need to conditionally render.. for date we have a specific render component.. for other strings we have another component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody is facing the same issue, In my case I was getting an API response from a node server which had a string as its response. The string contained date in ISO format or anything else in it. Assuming you get a date within the string ISO format only. The solution is as follows

```js
moment('abc 12', moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid()
```

Output -

```
False
```

P S credits: My friend helped with this, he doesn't want to write the answer, which is why I just did.

Comment: verified it works 

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-moment-forked-y4gt9

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set a `strict mode` in moment, which will identify the parsing error and set the moment object as `Invalid Date`. I leave here some example:

```js
const strangeString = 'abc 123'; // You date with problem
const now = moment().format(); // Real date

const nowNoStrict = moment(now);
const nowStrict = moment(now, true);
const strangeStringNoStrict = moment(strangeString);
const strangeStringStrict = moment(strangeString, true);

document.getElementById("nowNoStrict").innerHTML = nowNoStrict.format();
document.getElementById("nowStrict").innerHTML = nowStrict.format();
document.getElementById("strangeStringNoStrict").innerHTML = strangeStringNoStrict.format();
document.getElementById("strangeStringStrict").innerHTML = strangeStringStrict.format();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Now string without use strict mode of moment </td>
    <td id="nowNoStrict"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Now string with use strict mode of moment: </td>
    <td id="nowStrict"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Your strange string whitout strict mode of moment: </td>
    <td id="strangeStringNoStrict"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Your strange string whit strict mode of moment: </td>
    <td id="strangeStringStrict"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To use `strict mode`, simply pass a second value as a boolean to the `moment` constructor (true to use it).

```js
var currentDate = moment('abc 123', true);
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = currentDate.format();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"><div>
```

Your code become

Comment: You've given an answer that does not work. just running the code snippet reveals the same.

Comment: Try the second snippet of code, it return your "Expected Output" -> "Invalid date".

Comment: The first code return a wargning, but if you exapand to "Full page" the running code you can see all examples.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 `<input type='date' />` would seem to circumvent that issue. Additionally, there are datepicker plugins of course a plenty from jQuery: https://www.vandelaydesign.com/30-best-free-jquery-plugins/

Then, if you want to roll your own, you can use an input mask like this one: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

The point of it all - to force a readable format from the user.

If you're just checking a string from somewhere for a possible date, you're still stuck with guessing what format to check for. Hence, it's best to force the user to input the date in your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. Looks like you are getting the input from a webpage (frontend)

If you are finding it difficult to do datetime checks backend, I'd suggest you use a date-picker plugin like [react-day-picker](https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker) if that is what your frontend speaks!

Comment: I am the author's colleague. The data comes from Api. Its a generic field, it can come with plain string or an iso date string. We need to conditionally render.. for date we have a specific render component.. for other strings we have another component